# Getting MikTex on Windows 8 to run

Tags: miktex, windows

I downloaded MiKtex 2.9 for windows 8 64 bit, but I can't find out how to run that software as there is no shortcut on desktop or on the APP page.
If any one has used Miktex on windows 8 OS then please help me on the issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX.  You need to run `pdflatex` on your document from the command line.  A quick google search for 'LaTeX introduction' should get you started, or you can run `texdoc lshort`.

Comment: I guess the right shortcut is to TeXnicCenter - maybe if you search for the .exe, you will have a link you can turn into a shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

MiKTeX includes TeXWorks, a (basic) editor for (La)TeX. If you search in windows 8 you'll find it. Sometimes apps/programs don't get added to the start screen, so manually pin this to start.

Other options are to use your own favorite text editor(check the list at [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) for good editors) and use the commandline to run `pdflatex document.tex` or `texify -p -b document.tex`(-p for pdf, -b for non-interactive mode).

If you need a syntex-file, use the following command with texify: `texify -p -b --tex-option="--synctex=1" document.tex`.